# How to have a rails model establish connection conditionally based on environment type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a rails model that looks like this:

```
class Db_Prod_Write < ActiveRecord::Base
    establish_connection :prod_write 
    self.abstract_class = true
end
```

`:prod_write` is a production environment defined in my database.yaml file.

This model (Db_Prod_Write) is being used in another model in a method that establishes a connection. The problem is, that when the method is running in QA environment, it still runs the method in production. Is there a way for me to make `establish_connection :prod_write` in the above code conditional so that it only establishes if the environment is production?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
establish_connection(:prod_write) if Rails.env.production?
```

Answer (score 1):

Test any of:

- `ENV['RAILS_ENV']`
- `RAILS_ENV`
- `Rails.env`
- `Rails.env.production?`

Comment: You mean like `establish_connection :prod_write if Rails.env.production?`...?